# Iterating through a list and querying a value

Tags: python-3.x, list

Suppose you have a list of teams keys name and type as shown below

```
teams = [

    {"Name": "Manchester",
     "Type": "Soccer"
     },
    {
        "Name": "Chelsea",
        "Type": "Soccer"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Lakers",
        "Type": "Basketball"
    }
]

teamStr = ""

#iterate through the list and concatenate to teamStr the team whose type is Soccer 
for index in teams:
    for value in teams[index].items:
        if value == "Soccer":
            teamStr += value
```

If say you wanted to iterate through the list and get the names of Soccer teams only. For example I want to get Chelsea and Manchester as output, In a nutshell I'd like to  iterate through the list and concatenate to teamStr the team whose type is Soccer, such that the final teamStr = "Manchester, Chelsea"

Comment: Replace `teams[index]` with `index`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through the list by calling `Type` keys in every iteration

```
for i in range(len(teams)):
    if teams[i]['Types'] == 'Soccer':
        teamStr += teams[i]['Name']
```

I haven't put spaces between team names, but if you want that:

```
for i in range(len(teams)):
    if teams[i]['Types'] == 'Soccer':
        teamStr += teams[i]['Name'] + ' '
    teamStr.rstrip(' ') #To remove the unwanted whitespace at the end
```

Comment: Yes I needed it to have some space. Works

Comment: @PlopMon you may want to [learn and use Python's for loops the right way](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements). And about [`str.join(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join] too FWIW.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers if you're talking about using `range` to iterate over the list instead of iterating directly... That thought didn't come to me at first 

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
soccerTeams = [team['Name'] for team in teams if team['Type'] == 'Soccer']
print(soccerTeams)
# ['Manchester', 'Chelsea']
teamStr = ', '.join(soccerTeams)
print(teamStr)
# Manchester, Chelsea
```

Comment: And THIS is the pythonic solution (should be the accepted answer).